# Having different Overlays with picture buttons, but it only opens one overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
/*when you click on the picture it should open an overlay, which closes if you click anywhere*/
<script type="text/javascript">
        
         
 
function on()    {document.getElementById("over1").style.display="block";}
             
         function off() {
  document.getElementById("over1").style.display = "none";
}    
       
         function on()    {document.getElementById("over2").style.display="block";}
             
         function off() {
  document.getElementById("over2").style.display = "none";
}    </script>
```

```css
 <style> 
.container{
         background-color: #94AB98;
         height:370px;
         width:280px;
         margin: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
         float: left;
         display: inline-block;
     } 
      .container .bildbt1{
          width: 230px;
         height: 230px;
         margin: 25; 
        border: none;
         background: url(pic1);
     }
     
     .container .bildbt2{
          width: 230px;
         height: 230px;
         margin: 25; 
        border: none;
         background: url(pic2);}
     
     #over1{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(65, 84, 80, 0.95);
         position: fixed;
        top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: :0;
         line-height: 130%;
     }
         
         #over2{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(65, 84, 80, 0.95);
         position: fixed;
        top: 0;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: :0;
         line-height: 130%;
     }
     
     #text1{
         position: absolute;
         top:50%;
         left:50%;
         color: white;
         font-size: 20;
         transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
         -ms-transform: translate (-50%,-50%);
     }
         
         #text2{
         position: absolute;
         top:50%;
         left:50%;
         color: white;
         font-size: 20;
         transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
         -ms-transform: translate (-50%,-50%);
     }
</style>
```

```html
/*those are my containers, with buttons*/

<body>
 <div class="container">
             <div id="over1" onclick="off()">
                 
        <a id="text1">some text</a></div>
            
         <button class="bildbt1" onclick="on()">
            </button>
         <h2>text too</h2>
           
        </div> 
        
   
           <div class="container">
            <div id="over2" onclick="off()">
            <a id="text2">
               also text</a>
            </div>
         <button class="bildbt2" onclick="on()"></button>  
         <h2>and there is also text</h2>
          
        </div>

</body>
```

It only shows Overlay 2, i tried various options but it doesn't work.
Can you help me?
I'don't know why I can't poste this question...

- It looks like your post is mostly code; add some more details...
  i think there are enough details.

Comment: your second set of functions overrides your first set. Name them differently. Or better, inject a paramter -like the element id you want to turn on and off.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: You have 2 functions named `on()` and 2 functions named `off()` the second of each overrides the first. Either rename them so they have unqiue names or use only one of them but inject the distinct `id` of the element you want to show / hide